# Android SQL update query returns 1 but not updating

Tags: java, android, sql-update, android-sqlite

I'm trying to update a simple boolean value in an SQL table as per the docs here: [Updating DB Row, developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#UpdateDbRow)

When I attempt to update the table, the update statement returns 1 but after closing and re-opening the app the database remains unchanged. Here is the code:

*In MainActivity.java:*

```
 void CheckUncheckTodayTask (String taskID, boolean newState) {
    new CheckUncheckTodayTask().execute(taskID, String.valueOf(newState));
 }

 class CheckUncheckTodayTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // New value for one column
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TaskContract.TodayTask.COLUMN_NAME_COMPLETED, Boolean.valueOf(strings[1]));

        // Which row to update, based on the title
        String selection = TaskContract.TodayTask._ID+ " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { strings[0] };

        db.update(
                TaskContract.TodayTask.TABLE_NAME,
                values,
                selection,
                selectionArgs);

        return null;
    }

}
```

*In TodayTaskAdapter.java:*

```
mCompletedCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_today_completed);
mCompletedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            mCompletedCheckBox.setPaintFlags(mCompletedCheckBox.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            mCompletedCheckBox.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            ((MainActivity)activityContext).CheckUncheckTodayTask(String.valueOf((long)mCompletedCheckBox.getTag(R.id.tag_check_box)), true);
        } else {
            mCompletedCheckBox.setPaintFlags(mCompletedCheckBox.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            mCompletedCheckBox.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            ((MainActivity)activityContext).CheckUncheckTodayTask(String.valueOf((long)mCompletedCheckBox.getTag(R.id.tag_check_box)), false);
        }
    }
});
```

The click handler is indeed being called and passing a taskID value of 1 and a newState value of true when checked.

I have tried changing to using getWriteableDatabase, using LIKE instead of = in the where clause, and stepping through the code line-by-line, but no errors were thrown.

Thanks!

Comment: ``SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`` This bothers me.

Comment: Do you get new value if you read from database immediately after updating?

Comment: @RamandeepNanda Yes, that bothered me too but it's per the documentation and I've tried using writeable instead.

Comment: @DomenJakofčič f I read immediately after checking the box, it immediately unchecks itself.

Comment: I've ended up doing a manual remove then add, which works. Please let me know if you find out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

After you execute the query, you should call `SqliteDatabase` `setTransactionSuccessful()`, `endTransaction()`, and `close()` functions; 
Otherwise your update query won't take effect,

Here is my example:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase(); // open writable database
db.beginTransaction();

try {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_OID, order.getOrderId());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS, order.getStatus());
    values.put(KEY_ORDER_NUM,order.getOrderNum());
    values.put(KEY_ESHOP_CAT, order.getEShopCat());
    values.put(KEY_REFERENCE,order.getReference());
    values.put(KEY_REJECT_REASON,order.getRejectReason());
    values.put(KEY_CANCEL_REASON,order.getCancelReason());
    values.put(KEY_PICKUP_TIMESTAMP, TimeUtil.getDatetimeFromUnixTimestamp(order.getOrderReadyTimestamp()));

    int rows = db.update(TABLE_ORDERS, values, KEY_OID+" = ?", new String[]{order.getOrderId()});

    if(rows==1) { // check if update succeeded
       Log.d(TAG, "update current order success");
    } else {
       long rowId=db.insert(TABLE_ORDERS,null, values);
       if(rowId!=-1){
           Log.d(TAG, "add new order success");
       } else {
           throw new Exception("error occurred while insert order");
       }
    }

    } catch(Exception e) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Error: "+e.toString());
    } finally {
       // IMPORTANT : must set transaction successful after query done, otherwise changes wont take effect especially update query
       db.setTransactionSuccessful();
       db.endTransaction();
       db.close();
}
```